Tire replacement question for you bike bros
I bought an e-bike with 26 x 4.8 tires.
I cannot find replacements that are more for street use.
Will a 26 x 4.0 tire cause me problems?

The change won’t cause you any issues. It’s a minor change to smaller width.
Unless you’re changing both tires you’ll want to keep the back tire as the smaller one. There are various reasons for this (some are myths) but the most sensible is that the front tire handles all the steering traction so you want the best grip up front.
